# Simple Regex: match everything until the last dot

Tags: regex

Just want to match every character up to but not including the last period

```
 dog.jpg     -> dog
 abc123.jpg.jpg -> abc123.jpg
```

I have tried

```
(.+?)\.[^\.]+$
```

Comment: Did you have a question? SO isn't here to write your regular expressions for you.

Comment: what for case like `abcd`, `a.b.c.d.e`?

Comment: also, what you want is to remove the file extension??   why don't you use tools for that instead of REGEX?? like basename()?

Comment: no tools just need to learn this doesnt matter the flavor just for a learning process

Comment: testing this using  my outsystems platform

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use lookahead to assert the last dot character:

```
.*(?=\.)
```

[Live demo.](https://regex101.com/r/rI4pQ1/1)

Comment: there is no need of lookahead here..it only increases the number of steps

Comment: This will always match twice at the same location.

Answer (score 14):

This will do the trick

```
(.*)\.
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rU9uD9/1)**

The first captured group contains the name. You can access it as `$1` or `\1` as per your language

Comment: this included the dot for me

Comment: @bigdowg where are you using it? its just showing the matched part.. the green part(in demo) shows the actual string you want

Answer (score 12):

Regular expressions are *greedy* by default. This means that when a regex pattern is capable of matching more characters, it will match more characters.

This is a good thing, in your case. All you need to do is match characters and then a dot:

```
.*\.
```

That is,

```
.   # Match "any" character
*   # Do the previous thing (.) zero OR MORE times (any number of times)
\   # Escape the next character - treat it as a plain old character
.   # Escaped, just means "a dot".
```

So: being greedy by default, match any character AS MANY TIMES AS YOU CAN (because greedy) and then a literal dot.