# Match everything before last dot regex

Tags: regex, text, tcl

I need a regex that will match everything before a last dot in my string. For example, I have text like this:
`if_blk4.if_blk1.if_blk1`
I would like to get the `if_blk4.if_blk1`.

Thanks!

Comment: `(.*)\.` Then get the result for matching group 1, e.g. $1 or \1 depending on the regex dialect.

Comment: This is a basic regex. What did you try? If you don't know the regex then [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions) is a good place to start.

Comment: Dupe  of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36801188/simple-regex-match-everything-until-the-last-dot/36801287

Answer (score 10):

To match everything up to (but not including) the last dot, use a look ahead for a dot:

```
.*(?=\.)
```

The greedy quantifier `*` makes the match include as of the input much as possible, while the look ahead `(?=\.)` requires the next character in the input to be a dot.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
regexp {.*(?=\.[^.]*$)} $text match
```

i.e. matching any characters that lead up to a (not matched) sequence of dot and zero or more characters that aren't dots, followed by the end of the string.

(The regular expression `{.*(?=\.)}` is equivalent as regular expression matching doesn't need to be anchored.)

or (faster)

```
file rootname $text
```

Documentation:
[file](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/file.htm),
[regexp](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regexp.htm),
[Syntax of Tcl regular expressions](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm)

Comment: Looking up from my own code, Andy's `(.*)\.` is much more elegant, with only the small disadvantage that one must use a capture group. But the `file rootname` variant is best.