# Regex to match all character other than period if it falls at end of line

Tags: regex

This seems like a simple thing, but I can't find an existing post that matches exactly what I'm looking for. I want a regex that captures everything in a line up to a possible period. So the following lines

```
This line has no number
This line has no number.
This line has 1.0 number
This line has 1.0 number.
```

all capture everything in the line up to the final period (if it exists).

Comment: Some other possible duplicates: *[Simple Regex: match everything until the last dot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36801188)*, *[How can I match "anything up until this sequence of characters" in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7124778)*.

Comment: That last one did it. Thanks!